# Does creating an Equifax account subject you to additional personal data collection?

Tags: united-states, credit-report, privacy

For creating an Equifax account, (for use with security freezes, for example), this is included in the [Terms of Use](https://www.equifax.com/terms/myequifaxterms/):

> You authorize and instruct Us to obtain, monitor, and compile Your: (i) credit information from EIS; (ii) "non-public personal information", "personal information", and/or "highly restricted personal information" about or concerning You as defined by the Gramm-Leach-Bliley Act (15 U.S.C. sec 6801 et seq); and (iii) other personal information.

Is this something Equifax does anyway, or does this subject you to more Equifax data collection than you would have without signing up for an account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The following is based on my reading of the agreement, but I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.*

**TL;DR**: The "Credit Reference Agency" part of the Equifax corporation will be collecting all that data anyway (as all "the big three" agencies do); what you are agreeing to is for the "myEquifax" part of the company – and anything involved in providing the infrastructure behind the website – to have *access* to that data.

From the preamble of the agreement:

> THIS MYEQUIFAX AGREEMENT AND TERMS OF USE ("AGREEMENT") CONTAINS THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS UPON WHICH YOU MAY CREATE AN ACCOUNT TO PERFORM CERTAIN ACTIONS RELATED TO YOUR CREDIT REPORT PROVIDED BY **EQUIFAX INFORMATION SERVICESS LLC (“EIS”)**

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

We note that **EIS** *provides* the "Credit Report": it is the body that collects and collates all your "credit-related" information and provides it to lenders, banks etc. as part of their main commercial operation. The collection of data *for* that report, and the provision of it to interested parties is not affected by this agreement.

The first clause of the agreement ends with some definitions:

> 1. [...] EIS **and its respective service providers** are collectively referred to in this Agreement as "**We**," "**Us**," and "**Our**." You, the person visiting and utilizing this Site or to create an Account, are referred to as "You" or "Your".

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

So "**We**", "**Us**" etc. mean both EIS (the collator of your credit report) and the *service providers* behind the *myEquifax* website and services (which may be other parts of the Equifax corporation and, possibly, third-party companies providing the infrastructure behind the website).

Therefore, in the section you quoted, you are agreeing that the "**Us**" that will have access to all your personal information includes both EIS (which *already* has access to pretty much all your personal information) *and* anything else necessary to provide the *myEquifax* website/services.